# Toolbar лого,которое возвращает на главную активность

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Я использую *Toolbar* с помощью *AppCompat v7:21*, и мне нужно сделать что-то наподобие этого:

[image: Gmail]

Чтобы по клике на лого возвращало на главную активность. Вот мой код:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Но  результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это *Appcompat* не поддерживает такую штуку как с картинкой *gmail*, чтобы возле лого не было такой стрелочки? Помогите найти решение пожалуйста.

Я был уже [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642378/), и перелопатил много тем англоязычного *stackoverflow*, но так и не нашел нужной информации.

Comment: Иконка приложения с маленькой стрелочкой это стиль андройда 4.х. Начиная с лолипопа стандартным считается большая стрелка без иконки, ну или с не нажимающейся иконкой на кряйняк. Если Вы всё же хотите использовать старый стиль, то Вам придется либо использовать AppCompat v7 не выше 20й версии. Либо очень серьёзно запариться с кастомизацией тулбара. Один мой коллега ходил по второму варианту и по его словам там придется обходить много багов сапорт либки. К сожалению к его коду у меня доступа нет так что подробнее описать не могу.

Comment: @xkor спасибо за подсказку, 2 вариант очень муторный, если я поменяю appCompat на 20 версию ничего страшного не будет??

Comment: блин хотя будет проблема, дело в том что я в дальенйшем хочу использовать RecyclerView , то там нужно ставить com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0... так что наверно все прийдеться оставить как есть